# Set cookie with Owa_cookie package

Tags: oracle-apex

My application required custom authentication, along with username and password I have another field at login page called "Company Code".

I need to save this "Company Code" in browser's cookie, so the next time they login, they won't have to re-enter that field. Here's what I did:

In login page, I created a process named "Set Co Code Cookie":

```
Begin

If :P9999_REMEMBER = 'Y' then

owa_util.mime_header('text/html', FALSE);

OWA_COOKIE.SEND(

           'MY_CO',

           :P9999_CO_CODE,

           SYSDATE +30);

owa_util.http_header_close;

end if;

end;
```

But nothing happen when running, no cookie are set on the browser.

What could be my mistake?

Comment: Are you sure your process is being executed? What execution point is it on?

Answer (score 1):

Richard Martens wrote about this a while ago:
https://smart4solutions.nl/blog/and-thats-how-the-cookie-crumbles/

In short, here's what you need to do:

1. In the page properties, set "Reload on Submit" to "Always".
2. On the standard login page, there is a process to clear the page cache. Make sure your process runs before that.